# AngularJS: how do I pass an :id parameter from Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I need to get data from my Ruby on Rails application, for that I made a pretty simple AngularJS controller:

```
# /app/assets/javascripts/angular/comments.js.coffee

app.controller 'CommentsController', ['$http', ($http) ->
  store = this
  store.comments = []

  $http.get('/photos/3287.json').success (data) ->
    store.comments = data

  return
]
```

It works absolutely fine with the hard-coded `:id`, but I'm stuck with how to make it change dynamically. What is the easiest way to get an `:id` from Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you wanna edit it? So, you shouldn't use AJAX, you should create `factory` and use Angular `$resource`, so you fetch it with `:id`, set it to `$scope`, and use it in future.

[MORE ABOUT Angular $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) - use Angular way

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can include `:id` in the URL and then pass the `id` as a parameter to the `get`.

```
# /app/assets/javascripts/angular/comments.js.coffee

app.controller 'CommentsController', ['$http', ($http) ->
  store = this
  store.comments = []

  $http.get('/photos/:id.json', {id: photo.id}).success (data) ->
    store.comments = data

  return
]
```

EDIT: I may have misunderstood. This is how you *pass* an id to `$http`, but if you need to get the id itself use `$resource` as Oleg had answered.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. Here is my working code.

```
# comments.js.coffee

app = angular.module('comments', ['ngResource'])

app.controller 'CommentsController', ['$scope', 'GetComments', ($scope, GetComments) ->

  store = this
  store.response = []

  $scope.init = (photo_id) ->
    GetComments.get({id: photo_id}).$promise.then (data) ->
      store.response = data.toJSON().comments
      return
  return
]

app.factory 'GetComments', ['$resource', ($resource) ->
  $resource('/photos/:id.json', null)
]
```

Also I had to add `ng-init` to my view like this:

```
# foo.html.haml

%div{'ng-controller' => 'CommentsController', 'ng-init' => "init(#{@photo.id})"}
```